# Auto replace value to foreign key id?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have an SQL table:

```
TestResult
- id
- test_result 
- test_name
```

Every testing makes one session which creates about 1000 records in **TestResult** table, and I found that I have now a lot of **test_name** duplication here.

How is it correct to get ride off duplication?

I think that it is correct create two tables:

```
TestName
- name (Primary Key)

TestResult
- id (Primary Key)
- result
- name_id (Foreign Key)
```

But how can I automatically replace for example 'test_1' to 1 (id from TestName table) ?

Should I in each step of my 1000 tests cycle do this?
1. Try to get name_id if exists
2. If not exists create it
3. Add record to TestResult using previous id.

I think that is too slow and stupid. What is the good practice here? Or maybe it is a good idea to let it be as it is?

Comment: see answer below...

Answer (score 0):

setup the tables but keep test_name column along with test_id (new FK), then:

```
UPDATE T SET
    T.name_id = tn.name
FROM TestResult T
INNER JOIN TestName TN on 
    T.test_name = TN.name
```

Comment: Normalization in this case does not make any sense, because you are still duplicating the names, 

Instead, I would have TestName(id int not null primary key identity, name varchar(xxxx) not null)

Then TestResult has the id as the foreign key, maybe that is what you meant after all.

Comment: But how associate it automatically?

Comment: you can't, I have had similar cases like this where first we check if in your case, the name exists on the names table, if true, then grab the sid where the name matches and use that on the insert on the testresult, otherwise you insert the new test name on the testname table, get the generated identity, then use that to insert to testresult.